# convert SQL query with multiple join on multiple tables using group by on multiple columns and with aggregate function into LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, sql-server-2008

Please help me to convert below query into LINQ syntax.

```
select am.areaid, am.AreaName, MAX(am.pincode),count(ua.ApartmentID) from areamaster am 
inner join MerchantServiceAreas msa on am.areaid = msa.areaid
left join apartmentmaster apm on am.areaid = apm.areaid
left join useraddress ua on apm.apartmentid = ua.apartmentid
group by am.areaid,am.areaname
```

I have tried with the following syntax but doesn't work

```
(from ar in Entities.AreaMasters
    join mrs in Entities.MerchantServiceAreas on ar.AreaID equals mrs.AreaID

    join ap in Entities.ApartmentMasters on mrs.AreaID equals ap.AreaID into apl
    from ap1 in apl.DefaultIfEmpty()

    join ua in Entities.UserAddresses on ap1.ApartmentID equals ua.ApartmentID into ual
    from ua1 in ual.DefaultIfEmpty()

    where mrs.MerchantID == MerchantID
    group ar 
    by new
    {
      ar.AreaID,
      ar.AreaName,
      ar.Pincode
    } into uag
    select new AreaComplex
    {
      AreaID = uag.Key.AreaID,
      AreaName = uag.Key.AreaName,
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: What isn't working about it? Unexpected results, exceptions?

Comment: unexpected result

Comment: Then please describe more. explain what your data looks like, what you are currently getting and what you expected to get

Comment: ORMs are *not* meant to execute reporting queries. Converting this reporting query to LINQ is a bad idea. The very fact that you need all this code is a very, very strong warning that you are doing it wrong

Comment: At the very least create a view that hides the joins and exposes only the columns required for reporting. Map EF to this query, so you can create a *simple* LINQ query that doesn't require any joins.

Answer (score 0):

in your grouping remove ar.Pincode

```
   group ar 
    by new
    {
      ar.AreaID,
      ar.AreaName,
      ***ar.Pincode***
    } into uag
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Code:

```
var result=  (from ar in Entities.AreaMasters
join mrs in Entities.MerchantServiceAreas on ar.AreaID equals mrs.AreaID

join ap in Entities.ApartmentMasters on mrs.AreaID equals ap.AreaID into apl
from ap1 in apl.DefaultIfEmpty()

join ua in Entities.UserAddresses on ap1.ApartmentID equals ua.ApartmentID into ual
from ua1 in ual.DefaultIfEmpty()

where mrs.MerchantID == MerchantID
group new { ar,mrs,ap1,ua1 }
by new
{
  ar.AreaID,
  ar.AreaName      
} into uag
select new AreaComplex
{
  AreaID = uag.FirstOrDefault().ar.AreaID,
  AreaName = uag.FirstOrDefault().ar.AreaName,
  Pincode=  uag.Max(c=>c.ar.pincode),
  Pincode=  uag.Count(c=>c.ua1.ApartmentID),
}).ToList();
```

Comment: `.AsEnumerable()` executes the query represented by an IQueryable. You call it 4 times, resulting in 4 executions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax ,

```
(from am in Entities.AreaMasters.GetQueryable()
 join msa in Entities.MerchantServiceAreas.GetQueryable()
.Where(a=> a.MerchantID == MerchantID) on am.AreaID equals msa.AreaID
join apm in Entities.ApartmentMasters.GetQueryable() on am.AreaID equals 
apm.AreaID into apmjoin from apmlj into apmjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
join ua in Entities.UserAddresses.GetQueryable() on apmlj.ApartmentID equals 
ua.ApartmentID into uajoin from ualj in uajoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { newAreaID = am.AreaID,newAreaName =  am.AreaName, newPincode= 
am.Pincode})
.GroupBy(a=> new {AreaID = a.newAreaID,AreaName = a.newAreaName,Pincode= 
a.newPincode})
.Select(x=> new AreaComplex { AreaID = x.FirstOrDefault().AreaID,
AreaName = x.FirstOrDefault().AreaName,Pincode = x.Sum(a=>a.Pincode) }).toList();
```

Comment: Its only an instance of entity , if we apply `GetQueryable()` then it becomes `IQueryable` else you can not use `Where()` also

Comment: How do you know that unless you sit right next to the OP? In *any* LINQ to EF query, these are *Queryables*. In fact, the OP's query *already* works without requiring any `GetQueryable()` method

Comment: Neither `DbSet` nor `IQueryable` have a `GetQueryable` method. Other, unrelated classes do, eg QueryableFilterUserControl or the expression classes used by the QueryExtender control. None of these are necessary when you *already* have access to the context